# Not sure how to update a struct with new information

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

A question concerning Bixby Studio.

I am trying to figure out how to accept text-input from the user.

I have a Filter struct with some fields such as SearchField, Genre, Platforms (Gaming consoles), and Themes (A few other entries)

By default, all of these are optional, especially with the search field. However, i would like for the user to be able to visibly see what filters are enabled, and be able to select and change their values (This values can be overwritten by NLP training, but I can't figure out how to disable the field.)

I created a result view for my filters and I've setup input-cells for selecting a specific field to modify. (In this case, SearchField.). I have been successful in redirecting to an input-view, but it seems that no matter what text I put in here, it does not save or apply to my filter.

Looking for some insight into the problem and willing to provide more information as needed.

Some of the things that I have tried in the past, seem to want take the existing context "SearchField" within the filters (which might not exist) and apply it to the new "search field". However, this doesn't work and seems to create a loop.

I've also tried to set the `prompt-behavior (AlwaysSelection)` in the action model for SetSearchField, but it appears to do nothing.

```
// Result View for Filters
result-view {
  match {
    Filter(this)
  }
  message {
    template (Active Filters){
      speech (Would you like to change any filters?)
    }
  }
  render {
    layout-macro (filter-details) {
      param (filter) {
        expression (this)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
// Layout Macro

layout-macro-def(filter-details) {
  params {
    param (filter) {
      type (Filter)
      min (Required)
      max (One)
    }
  }

  content {
    section {
      title (Filters)
      content {
        input-cell {
          label (Search Name)
          value ("#{value(filter.name)}")
          on-click {
            intent {
              goal: SetSearchField // <-------- Field in question
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
// Input-view for SearchField

input-view {
  match {
    SearchField(searchField)
  }
  render {
    form {
      elements {
        text-input {
          id (val)
          type (SearchField)
          required (true)
        }
      }
      on-submit {
        goal:SearchField
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
// SetSearchField action
action (SetSearchField) {
  description (Sets the name in a search filter)
  type (Fetch)
  collect {
    input (newSearchField) {
      type (SearchField)
      min (Required)
      prompt-behavior (AlwaysSelection)
    }
  }
  output (SearchField)
}
```

```
// SetSearchField endpoint
    action-endpoint (SetSearchField) {
      accepted-inputs (newSearchField) 
      local-endpoint ("filters/SetSearchField.js")
    }

// .js file

module.exports.function = function setName (newSearchField) {
  return newSearchField
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I discovered there is a special way in accessing input form elements for input-views.

Collect input through the `form` -> `elements`, then reference them using the `viv.core.FormElement(id)`

```
input-view {
  match {
    SearchField(searchField)
  }
  render {
    form {
      on-submit {
        goal: SearchField
        value: viv.core.FormElement(text)
      }
      elements {
        text-input {
          id (text)
          type (SearchField)
          label (Search for: )
          value("#{raw(searchField)}")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```